# Eclipse - how to disable error message that prevents startup

Tags: eclipse, qnx

I'm using a QNX-based Eclipse `momentics-qnx-7.0-201607252121.win32.x86_64`

Apparently it doesn't like it when you store it in a location that has spaces.

When I start Eclipse, I get a modal message

> "installation directory of IDE or SDK ... contains space characters, it may cause untraceable errors during make. You should exit the IDE and fix the error"

But when I click **OK** it just exits the IDE.

It looks like this was an error message added specifically by QNX.

For me, this message is irrelevant because I don't use the built-in `make`.

**QUESTION**

Is there a way for me to disable this message (like `.ini` file)?

It works fine moving it to a location with no space in path.

Comment: Did you try moving it to a location without spaces in the path? You didn't say.

Comment: @nitind yes it works fine there.